# WPF stringformat show only digital

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

i want in wpf application show only decimal number in a textblock.

I have for example "35.56", i want show only ".56"

Thank you

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=yourprop, StringFormat={}{#.0}}" />` **or** `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=yourprop, StringFormat={#.0}}" />` these are a few options.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent **0**.56 as only `.56` using `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=yourprop, StringFormat='#.##'}" />` but `35.56` cannot be represented using `.56` using a `StringFormat` because `35.56` and `.56` are two different values.

If you want to represent `35.56` as `.56` for some strange reason, you'd better format the `string` using some custom logic in your view model:

```
public string YourPropFormatted
{
    get
    {
        string s = yourprop.ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        int index = s.IndexOf('.');
        return (index > 0) ? s.Substring(index) : s;
    }
}
```

XAML is a markup language and can't handle this.

Comment: The number I want to show is always 35.56, but 35 with a textblock and a larger fontsize, because more important and .56 with another textblock and a small font...

Comment: @Kiffer: It makes no difference to the answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing mm8 answer with another way to get the same result is implementing a `IValueConverter`.

```
public class NumberToDecimalPartConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(!(value is double val))
            return default(double).ToString(); // or ".00", you decide

        string s = val.ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        int index = s.IndexOf('.');

        return index > 0 ? s.Substring(index) : s;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // you don't need convert back
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Assuming the converter is placed at same namespace

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NumberToDecimalPartConverter x:Key="NumberToDecimalPart"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=yourprop, Converter={StaticResource NumberToDecimalPart}}" />
```

When your property changes, the `UI` will be updated, right?
With converter, you have one more step that is convert the value.

So what I'm doing here it's when the property (your probably `double` value) change, the WPF will call the `Convert` function from `NumberToDecimalPartConverter`. When the property have `Mode` setted as `TwoWay` will call `ConvertBack`.